# What would cause both nodes on a CAN bus to both exhibit bit dominant errors?

Tags: embedded, can-bus

I have 2 nodes connected on a CAN bus. The bus layout exists in the following manner:

Node 1 -> Node 2 -> 120 Ohm Terminator (GridConnect CAN terminator)

Attempting to transmit on either mode leads to “bit dominant errors”. I’m not sure if I’m misunderstanding how termination works, but it seems like an issue that, based on what I’ve read elsewhere, could be caused by faulty termination. Of course, I have my CANH/CANL/CANGND on Node 2 connected to the CAN terminator. Do I need another terminator connected to Node 1 as well?

If termination is not the issue, what are some other possible causes? Transmission is impossible for either node so it indicates both nodes can attempt to send a dominant bit on the bus but reading back every time. I haven’t attached a scope yet but I’d assume what I’d be seeing is the CAN TX pin refusing to go low? Because this is what would seem to cause an issue where the node expects to be sending a dominant bit on the bus but reading back a recessive one

Comment: for electronics question, try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/can

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic and belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: As for what could be the cause, likely various hardware problems. To begin with, make sure to measure 60 ohm between CANH and CANL. Then check this: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Answer (score 1):

You need terminators on both sides between CANH and CANL. Make sure that you have connected CANH with CANH and CANL with CANL.

120 Ohm <- Node 1 <-> Node 2 -> 120 Ohm

**Pleas ask this kind of questions in electronics stack exchange, see maxy 's comment above.**